# Wxpython reads data from a table, instantiating each row of data into an object

Tags: object, grid, wxpython

I want to achieve in wxpython this library to read the grid table data, each read a row of data in the table can instantiate an object, this line of data is the parameters of this object. The following is the code

```
import wx
import wx.grid
class TestFrame(wx.Frame):
    col_name=['name','age','address','tele_number']
    def __init__(self):
        wx.Frame.__init__(self,None,title='sss',size=(500,433))
        grid=wx.grid.Grid(self)
        grid.CreateGrid(50,50)
        for row in range(4):
            grid.SetColLabelValue(row, self.col_name[row])
            for  col in range(4):
                grid.SetCellValue(row,col,'cell(%d,%d)'%(row,col))
app=wx.App()
a=TestFrame()
a.Show()
app.MainLoop()
```